# How do I query columns from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I need to write a `SELECT` query that reports specific data from a table. My issue is that one column I need to report is normalized into another table.

I need to report C/SRep that is located in table `Consultant`. FK `ConsultantID` resides within the table `Clients`.

```
SELECT 
    ClientName, Country, City, State, Province, Zip, 
    [Address 1], [Address 2], InvestorContact, ConsultantID
FROM
    Clients
INNER JOIN 
    Consultant ON ConsultantID = C/SRep
```

The above lines are one thing I have tried.

Result:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Ambiguous column name 'ConsultantID'
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid column name 'C'
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Invalid column name 'SRep'
>
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Ambiguous column name 'ConsultantID'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify *all* column references when you write queries, and you will never have this problem.  Of course, I don't know the data, but the idea is:

```
SELECT cl.ClientName, cl.Country, cl.City, cl.State, cl.Province, cl.Zip, cl.[Address 1], cl.[Address 2],
       co.InvestorContact, co.ConsultantID
FROM Clients cl JOIN
     Consultant co
     ON cl.ConsultantID = co.ConsultantID;
```

I just made up where the columns come from.

Comment: How do I qualify all column references? Thank you for responding!

Comment: @JMBurnworth . . . By including the alias for the table where the column comes from.

Comment: SELECT Clients.ClientName, Clients.Country, Clients.City, Clients.State, Clients.Province, Clients.Zip, Clients.[Address 1], Clients.[Address 2], Clients.InvestorContact, Consultant.[C/SRep]
FROM Clients
 JOIN Consultant
 ON Clients.ConsultantID=Consultant.ConsultantID;

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Yes. Thank you for checking. Trying to get help on Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric now x.x

Comment: @DaleK I had already upvoted GordonLinoff's answer, but wasn't sure how to accept it. I am still learning the layout of this website and was very tired when I tried to find a way to close the problem. I have accepted the answer now. Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a basic sql class like the one here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ the question you asked shows that you are missing some pertinent knowledge to working with sql